# RestTemplateBuilder setConnectTimeout not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

When I use auto-configured bean of `RestTemplateBuilder`, the timeout field doesn't set as intended.

code:

```
    public WebHookService(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
                .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                .build();
```

Result:
[image: Result]

However When I set the custom bean of RestTemplateBuilder, timeout is set as Intended.

code:

```
    @Bean
    RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder();
    }
 
    // ...

    public WebHookService(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
                .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                .build();
```

Result:
[image]

As far as I know, `In Spring Boot 1.4.0 application RestTemplateBuilder is available as a bean and you can simply use that`.
So there should be no difference between using custom bean and auto-configured bean.
... But it didn't!

Anyone who knows why?

Comment: What is this `WebHookService` and how is it created/managed? Also, what version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Thank you for pointing out the important aspect. `WebHookService` class is managed as `@Service`, and spring boot 3.1.0 is what I'm using.

Comment: Although I can think of at least 3 different ways to achieve the same thing, it should work as shown. The simplest debugging you can do it to put a breakpoint in the `build` method, and see what it does. You didn't show at which point you're checking the timeout values, and depending on the lifecycle, that might matter. Your question lacks debugging details.